# Android 10 navigaton crash after AndroidX migration

Tags: android, androidx

I have migrated my app into Anrdoid x few days ago and facing a bizzare issue that it is getting crash only on Android 10 samsung devices after navigating from one activity to other, and it also not gets logged in logcat as well as on crashlytics.
Any one can help me out please

Answer (score 0):

I personally also had a similar issue like yours. In my case I had to change some Imports.

For example:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

has to be changed to:

```
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
```

If this does not work please update your question with some code. Without code, it's a bit difficult to help.